# Android Video recording with controls?

Tags: android, video

I need to capture the video with standard controls , at present i can capture the video using mediarecorder, I need a timer to show duration of video recording and some standard control to record video. Is there any other class is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard approach to record video in Android is to use  Intent MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE. You get timer and controls like when you start standard video capture. The only additional option is that you can accept or reject recorded video, since recorded video info is returned back via Intent result (so you can also conclude if user canceled video recording).